# How to make a UINavigationBar NOT push down views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, uikit

I have multiple `UIViewController`s in a `UINavigationController`. Sometimes I show the bar, sometimes I don't. How do I make the navigation bar show without pushing down the view?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The navigation bar will always push down the view unless it's set to be translucent.

Answer (score 0):

You can override pushViewController: method